# How to output response to command line through code

Tags: go, cmd, exec

I welcome everyone!

There is a code generator that I cover with tests.
Code generation takes place in stages - one command - one new layer (for example, generating a client's GRPS).
If I miss that which is needed, the code tells me via the command line: "You don't have an initial application structure generated. Generate (yes/no)?" and waiting for the answer there.

on manual testing, everything is easy and clear, but I create a situation where the code itself must answer "yes" on the command line and the generation continues without my direct intervention.

tried

> "exec.Command("yes").Output()

> exec.Command("yes").Stdout

did not help

Comment: Are you asking how to execute a command with standard input  "yes\n"?

Comment: Yes. from tests

Comment: The [exec.Command example](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#example-Command) shows how to set standard input to a specified string.